# communication between processes running on two machines

Tags: java, linux, process

So, I have two Linux machines, I am running a java code on machine A and doing ssh to run some simulation on machine B. What are the ways in which I can pass the result back to machine A when it is done with computations (I do not want to use a db). The results are mainly Status messages of each module, if it performed as expected or not. Also how to track the status of simulation running of machine B (I can check pid of process, if it exists then the job is running, but is there any better method). Machine B has some security restrictions, like I can not open a port etc.

Comment: are you using jsch to run your ssh?  If so if you create a `shell` channel you can write back the results using the channels outputstream

Comment: Use message consumers on machine A that listen to topics which will have messages published to them when the SSH script completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jSCH

```
    JSch shell = new JSch();
    session = shell.getSession(userName, serverIP, 22);  
    session.setPassword(password);

        session.setTimeout(timeout);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();      

        channel = session.openChannel("shell");  
        input = new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream(), encoding);  
        output = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());  

        channel.connect(); 

            output.write ("/home/test/runCommand");

            // result
            while ((ch = input.read () != -1) {....}
```